# how to automatically cleanup failed Wordpress uploads in /tmp?

Tags: admin, uploads

How do we automatically cleanup failed Wordpress uploads that are in /tmp ?
Say delete everything that is 3+ days old.

Comment: Most hosting environments automatically clear old items out of `/tmp` on their own schedule... You theoretically shouldn't need to do anything. Do you wish to remove items specifically added by Wordpress and leave the other files alone? Or are you wishing to clear the **entire** `/tmp` directory of items 3+ days old? If you do wish to clear the entire directory, what don't you like about your server's current handling of the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: This is our own private server, not a hosting provider, so we need to do our own housekeeping.  And we cannot just delete everything as other applications also use /tmp to host their transient files.

Comment: Your own proprietary server? Did you write it in Node.js or some such? Because its typical for Apache and NGINX to clear `/tmp` on a cron schedule, and PHP should remove anything it added and left in the `/tmp` directory at the end of script execution (even for failed uploads)... While you could use the [WP Cron Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions) to manually clean up `tmp`, I would argue that if your `/tmp` directory isn't already clearing on a regular schedule something is funky in your server, cron, or PHP config and you should attack the issue at its source...